# I installed phpMyAdmin, and skipped the step with password, now unable to do much

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I installed phpMyAdmin on Linux Jessie with the following steps:

installed mysql-server first

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

added

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
sudo service mysql restart

mysql -p -u root
mysql> CREATE DATABASE ha_test;
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ha_test.* TO 'maxg'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'maxe-pi';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

installed PHP for MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

then installed PMA

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

added at the end:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
sudo service apache2 restart`
```

At some stage a grey config screen came up asking about a password, and I could not figure which one; it offered to skip the step, and do the config later, but I do not know how to do this later and cannot open the ha_test database I created earlier.

The screen provided this info:

```
Creating config file /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php with new version
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
unable to connect to mysql server.
error encountered creating user:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
dbconfig-common: phpmyadmin configure: trying again.
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
Replacing config file /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf with new version
```

What should I do?

1. purge the install and start over? Is the user/pw it is asking for the root user and password I had created earlier or my own?
2. is there a way to fix this?
3. anything else?

I closed PMA and logged in again and it said:

The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated.

I reckon this is a result of the missed config step.

Answer (score 1):

Look into "/etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf" and check for

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourpassword';
```

Here you have to provide the mysql root password.

Comment: This files contains lots of config items which all start with `dbc_` e.g. a dbc_user, dbc_pass, but also a dbc_admin. Am I looking at the right file?

Comment: If you installed from packet source i think the right location is "/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php". The error basically tells you that cant access to the database because you have a wrong password in the config files.

Comment: This file explicitly states in the header comments not to put passwords in it: ```NOTE: do not add security sensitive data to this file (like passwords) unless you really know what you're doing...```